# creating and removing divs in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am showing images in divs. If the images is not in a div, I am currently hiding the div. However, depending on where there div is in the page, I would get plank spots on the page if the div is empty. I would like to collapse the div if it is empty. I am currently doing this:

html code:

```
    <div id="main" class="main1">
        <div id="div1" class="center"></div>
        <div id="div2" class="center"></div>
        <div id="div3" class="center"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="right" class="right1">
        <div id="div4" class="center"></div>
        <div id="div5" class="center"></div>
        <div id="div6" class="center"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(function () {
                $('#div3').html("").css({ "border": "", "margin": "0" });
                var myImage13 = new Image();
                $(myImage13).load(function () {
        $('#div3').show();
                $("#div3").html(myImage13).css({ "border": "2px solid #E0E0E0" });
                $('#div3').css({ "width": "500px", "height": "500px" });
                $('#div3 img').css({ "width": "500px", "height": "500px" });


                }).attr('src', img_src).error(function () {
                    $('#div3').html("").css({ "border": "", "margin": "0" });
            $('#div3').hide();
                })

            });
```

I tried $('#div3').remove(), but this completely removes the div. Any ideas how I can collapse the div if it is empty in jquery?

Comment: If you just want to hide the element: `$('#div3').hide();` but I'm not sure that I understand your question, but that might be because you've got no images in your provided HTML to illustrate what you're actually doing.

Comment: You are alrady using `$('#div3').hide();`. Is it not working ?

Comment: I have 6 divs, I dynamically assing images to these divs. but sometimes any one of them could be empty. If emtpy, is it possible to collapse the div so that next full div takes its place in the html. If I hide the div, its place still reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [.error](http://api.jquery.com/error/) jQuery doc:

> The event handler must be attached before the browser fires the error
>   event, which is why the example **sets the src attribute after attaching
>   the handler.** Also, the error event may not be correctly fired when the
>   page is served locally; error relies on HTTP status codes and will
>   generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol.

In other words, place `.error` after `.attr` in your code:

```
...
.error(function() {
  $('#div3').html("")
            .css({ border: '', margin: 0 })
            .hide();
}).attr('src', img_src)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
       $('div:empty').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  your div has no elements other than the image if any you can try this

```
var elems = $('#div1, #div2, #div3 , #div4, #div5', #div6);
$.each(elems , function(){
     if( $(this).children.length() < 1)){
       $(this).hide()
     }
});
```